# Ruby Rspec cucumber array each do

Tags: ruby, rspec, webdriver, cucumber

I have scenario when upon login to the page, I am presented with numerous profile(can be 1 to 5).
I am looking for specific profile based by tn number.
I locate element that represent tn and then put in array to search for all available elements with same to locate correct  profile in order to click on it.

Here is the code:

```
And(/^I look for "([^"]*)"$/) do |number|   
   elements = @driver.find_elements(:css => "h3.phone-number")   
   elements.each do |element|  
     renewals_page.select_profile.click if element.text == @config[number]  
       return element  
   end   
     fail  
end
```

I am passing desired number from `yaml` file depends on the account.
`renewals_page.select_profile.click` is defined in another file as method

```
  def select_profile   
    @driver.find_element(:css => "h3.phone-number")   
  end
```

So when I try to locate that element and click on it, I get following error

```
unexpected return (LocalJumpError)    
./features/step_definitions/renewals_login_step.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'    
./features/step_definitions/renewals_login_step.rb:26:in `each'    
./features/step_definitions/renewals_login_step.rb:26:in `/^I look for "([^"]*)"$/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `return` from here:

```
renewals_page.select_profile.click if element.text == @config[number]  
#   ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
#   return element  # removed
   element   # proper working return from lambda: result of last line
end
```

the reason is that return keyword may be used to return from `method` only, not from `lambda`.

Comment: when I do this, I get runtime error
 (RuntimeError)
./features/step_definitions/renewals_login_step.rb:30:in `/^I look for "([^"]*)"$/'
which does not say anything much

Comment: Of course you get a `RuntimeError` because you have a `fail` right after the the `each` loop. I could update my answer with fully working version of code, if I understood what you are trying to achieve. The thing is that you **cannot return from lambdas, period**.

Comment: for some reason, grabbing elements works, but in array, element is not passing text

Comment: That's not a lambda. It's a poorly formatted block for the enumerator. He can definitely `return` from that.

Comment: I think I am doing completely wrong. Would be better to find element and just click on such    
    elements.each do |element|
         if element.text == @config[number]
           element.click
         end

Comment: @Johnson You might go and try to execute `[1,2,3].each { |i| return i }` in your `irb`/`pry`. This **is** lambda, since every block is in fact lambda.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Apologies. I was thinking Cucumber steps were wrapped like a method, which would allow you to `return`. I deleted my answer below. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @mudasobwa, thank you, I am new to Ruby and this I was trying figure how to pass that

Comment: @Johnson You are welcome. Even if steps were wrapped in a methods, that `return` would return from _the method_ which is definitely not what OP expected.